# IE 9 compat view causes script to not load

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, nivo-slider

I'm working with jQuery and the code loaded fine and when I changed around the CSS and now gives me an illegal operation handle for jQuery. and now won't load in Compatability mode.

```
SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
index.php, line 124 character 1
```

I received from script debugging. I didn't receive this is any other browser.

My jQuery is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
});
});
</script>
```

Can someone tell where I went wrong?

Comment: Can you try removing comma from the line  `startSlide: 0,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma on this line:

```
startSlide: 0,
```

Should be:

```
startSlide: 0
```

Older versions of Internet Explorer don't support trailing commas in object notation.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the comma after the startSlide: 0

```
$(window).load(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0 // Remove the comma here
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you by any chance deleted the container from the page?

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```